# Is it "the present he" or "the present him"?

Tags: grammar

For example:

> The present he/him had no choice but to run away.

If reworded, I would put something like:

> He presently had no choice but to run away.

But then, it could also be reworded to:

> The person who presently had no choice but to run away was him.

From that, I *believe* that the correct one is "him", but I am uncertain.

Comment: 1. "him"; it is objective.
2. Correct
3. Correct; again objective.

Comment: You've got 3 different meanings there.  Only #2 is at all idiomatic.

Answer (score 3):

There is an idiomatic construction in English whereby we take *object* pronouns (me, you, him, her, them, etc.) and modify them with adjectives and sometimes definite articles. We then use these expressions in the *subject* positions of sentences.

For example, we say things like

- (the) real me loves to write.
- (the) real you hates your mother.
- (the) drunk me is fun, but (the) sober me is a bore.
- (the) drunk you is a monster.
- (the) real her would never do that.

This construction is not limited to the adjectives "real" and "drunk". It is productive. Some might think it sounds very marked, but to others (myself included) it sounds very natural.

I thus think that "The present him had no choice but to run away" is gramatically fine, albeit semantically weird. You're more likely to use "the present him" when you're contrasting him as he currently is with a previous version of himself, as in "The present him likes wine, but the younger him didn't".

Comment: Good (except that I'm not sure that 'generative' works for 'productive').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, point taken. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

Let's clear up the idiom first.  If you mean to say that right now retreat is the only choice, the you want "at present" or "currently."  "Presently" has two meaning -- either "currently" or "in a short while," so you may use that word as well.

Next, the pronoun's case.  The sentence structure is

> he (*subj*)   had (*verb)*   choice (*direct
>   object*)

The pronoun is the subject, so it takes the nominative case "he."

Finally, the verb.  If your choice of *adverb* means that you're talking about right now, then you'll need the **present tense** to describe his only option:

> *Currently*, he **has** no choice but to run away.

If your *adverb* has you talking about the near future, then you'll need the **future tense**:

> *Presently*, he **will have** no choice but to run away.

Comment: Great.  Another driveby downvoter, a plague on this site.

Comment: I just downvoted, but I won't drive by :) Here is the reason: I feel that when people turn pronouns into nouns, they use the objective case rather than the subjective case. For example: "The me from the parallel universe is evil. The real me is good." This is not common, and it can sound weird, but using a subject form sounds even worse in my opinion.

Comment: @sumelic Well, you've pretty much missed the point of the answer, but I'm still grateful for your explanation.  But, good God, man, the answer is from last August!

Comment: I feel like this answer misses the point of the question. The question asks about a sentence using the specific construction "The present he/him," but you don't use that in any of your example sentences. The original poster is aware that we normally use the nominative case for pronouns in the subject position; the question includes the example sentence "**He** presently had no choice but to run away." The question doesn't ask about which tense to use, or how to reword the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

This construction is tricky because it is rarely used and not at all straightforward. Google's n-gram viewer doesn't have "the present him" at all, and its data for "the present he" consists primarily (perhaps exclusively) of false positives.

Let's look at German and French first to see what is so difficult in English.

- German has a well preserved case and pronoun system that leaves no doubt that the nominative is what we need here. German does have an uncertainty, but it concerns only the gender: *der/das gegenwärtige Er*. The nominative in this context is well established because what is called *ego* in Freudian terminology is called *das Ich* in German, using the nominative of the German personal pronoun *I*.
- The case system of French is dissolving much like that of English. Moreover, the French pronouns are slowly being turned into clitics (an intermediate stage between full words and mere affixes), and their role is slowly being taken over by what is known as the emphatic pronouns. I think there can be no doubt that in French one should prefer to nominalise the emphatic pronouns rather than the clitics. And in fact, French for the Freudian *das Ich / the ego* is *le moi (the me)*, not *le je* (the I).

The English pronouns are more similar to the French ones than to the German system. The main difference is that some prescriptivists like to deny the existence of emphatic pronouns and pretend that cases in English work exactly as in German. According to them, *you and me* should be object case only, and the subject case should be *you and I*. As a result, a lot of people actually write like that in formal language. (Since this is not a natural rule of English there is a strong tendency towards the hypercorrection of using *you and I* even in the object case, as in "This does not matter to you and I". One can hear this so frequently that it has become acceptable, and in fact it sounds formal rather than wrong.)

According to the German logic, with its strong case system and absence of emphatic pronouns, it would have to be *the present he*. According to the French logic, with its declining case system and well established emphatic pronouns, it would have to be *the present him*. Now let's get back to English.

The first problem is that the emphatic pronouns are not yet considered fully acceptable in formal speech. This has led to the work-around of translating *das Ich* as *the ego*. This work-around doesn't really work for ad-hoc constructions in ordinary prose, and it certainly doesn't work for the masculine third person singular anyway, because in Latin that would be *is*.

The second problem is that *him* is much less systematically used as an emphatic variant of *he* than is the case for *me* as the emphatic variant of *I*. The answer to "Who is that?" will be *Me!* much more often than *I!*, but I think *He!* is still more common than *Him!* in most variants of spoken English.

Altogether, this is not a good stage in the evolution of English to nominalise *he*. Maybe you should just wait a few centuries until the fundamental changes that are currently in progress have completed. At the moment you have the choice between *the present he*, which sounds rather formal, and *the present him*, which sounds very informal. There is no neutral alternative other than avoiding the construction.